# Не запускается Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

[image]
При запуски появляется вот это. 
Если в загрузчике нажимаю е и дописываю nomedeset система запускается.  Драйвера на видеокарте обновлял. Intel i5 Intel HD graphics 530 Nvidia gtx 960m